# C++ is calculating wrong

Tags: c++

i have an inexplicable problem. Here is my code:

```
int result;
result = 0 * 2 ^ 1;
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

The result of this calculation is 1. But why? Actually it should be 0, shouldn't it?
I've tried it with the pow-function of the math-library but there the result also is 1:

```
int result;
result = std::pow(0 * 2, 1);
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: That's not the power/exponentiation operator. It's bitwise xor.

Comment: `^` is bitwise  exclusive OR

Comment: *"I've tried it with the pow-function of the math-library but there the result also is 1."* Can you show us how you use `pow` then?

Comment: Keep in mind that in C++ the `^` operator is the exclusive-or operator, not the power operator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Your second code definitely prints `0`: https://godbolt.org/z/f9QvH3

Comment: See https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/ and https://blog.plover.com/prog/compiler-error.html. Remember that the chances of you having the wrong expectations is much greater than the chances of a compiler incorrectly implementing basic operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, and many other computer programming languages, `^` means XOR *not* power-of. So it may not have the precedence you expected from mathematics.

Use [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) for exponents:

```
const int result = std::pow(0 * 2, 1);
std::cout << result << '\n';
```

Comment: @cigien What other kind is there?

Comment: You may want to warn about using pow with integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't knew it that ^ doesn't work likeI thinked.
But if std::pow not works, how I could do that otherwise?

Comment: @drescherjm Meh, not trying to replace the documentation.

Comment: @Coop4Free Don't ever assume you know what some symbol means/does in some programming language. Always look it up.

Comment: @cigien `!=` is the logical XOR

Comment: @＿Static＿assert Oh true. Then definitely worth pointing out that `^` is bitwise.

Comment: @Ast *"not trying to replace the documentation."* Did the documentation you provided address this point?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert It's not my responsibility to curate a full and complete list of all pertinent documentation. The OP can do some work too... or alternatively ask a fresh question after attempting to do so.

Comment: @Ast It's not your responsibility to do anything on this website. We're trying to create the best archive of programming knowledge here. drescherjm pointed out a common beginner mistake, and this post is likely to be only useful for beginners.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert Feel free to write an answer that you think is better

Comment: @ast If you don't feel like improving, why don't you community-wiki the answer so we can improve it freely?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert Why should I? You can write your own answer. Have a good night.

Comment: @ast so you're suggesting me to essentially duplicate this answer and only add one single side-note?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert I'm not going to teach you how the Q&A model works. Good night.